# testing dynamic android ui with robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I will have a ui which has buttons dynamically added to it. In order to test this I want to use robotum. I have two options on how to build the ui, using activities or using fragments. The latter seems to be a better option  for my situation but I read that  robotium does not support fragments. Is there any other option I could consider or am I incorrect in saying robotium does not support fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robotium does support fragments. In 3.4.1 there are even fragment specific methods like waitForFragmentById() etc.